# Bash sed replace with exact match of a text in a file

Tags: bash, sed, match

I have a file pattern.txt which is composed of one very long line of complicated code (~8200 chars).

This code can be found in multiple files inside multiple directories.

I can easily identify a list of these files using

```
grep -rli 'uniquepartofthecode' *
```

My concern is how do I replace it with the exact text from within the file ?

I tried to do:

```
var=$(cat pattern.txt)
sed -i "s/$var//g" targetfile.txt
```

but I got the following error :

> sed: -e expression #1, char 96: unknown option to `s'

sed is interpreting my $var content as a regular expression, I would like it to just match the exact text.

The pattern.txt content could be more or less any combination of characters so I'm afraid I cannot escape every characters efficiently.

Is there a solution using sed ? Or should I use another tool for that ?

EDIT:

I tried using this solution to make a proper regex pattern from my text file.
[Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)

the overall process is:

```
var=$(cat pattern.txt)

searchEscaped=$(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$var")

sed -n "s/$searchEscaped/foo/p" <<<"$var" # if ok, echoes 'foo'
```

This last command displays "foo". $searchEscaped seems to be properly escaped.
Though, this is not returning anything (it should display foo + the rest of the file without the matched part):

```
sed -n "s/$searchEscaped/foo/p" targetfile.txt
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed

Comment: Works great until 
`sed -n "s/$searchEscaped/foo/p" <<<"$search" # if ok, echoes 'foo'`
Then I try 
`sed -i "s/$searchEscaped//g" targetfile.txt`
but have no success

Comment: You are using `-n` this suppresses sed's output. Can you show your input file?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution is to not use regular expressions at all and resort to string replacement.

One way to do this is using perl:

```
$ echo "$string_to_replace"
some other stuff abc$^%!# some more
$ echo "$search"
abc$^%!#
$ perl -spe '$len = length $search; 
while (($pos = index($_, $search, $n)) > -1) { 
    substr($_, $pos, $len) = "replacement"; 
    $n = $pos + $len; 
}' <<<"$string_to_replace" -- -search="$search"
some other stuff replacement some more
```

The `-p` switch tells perl to loop through each line of the variable `$string_to_replace` (which could easily be replaced by a file). `-s` allows options to be passed to the script - in this case, I've passed a shell variable containing the search string.

For each line of the file, the `while` loop runs through all of the matches of the search string. `substr` is used on the left hand of the assignment to replace a substring of `$_`, which refers to the current line being processed.